# Registering Facebook Achievement - App-Access Token Issue

Tags: facebook-opengraph, access-token, facebook-access-token, achievements

I'm having a problem registering achievements:
I'm posting this code with the graph explorer:

[APPID]/achievements?access_token=[app access_token]&achievement=[achievement link]&display_order=1

..and I keep getting back: "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."

- I'm using the app access token, not a user access_token. (Obtained through this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ - but I've also used the technique described in the access_token docs - ie plugging: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials into your browser)
- I've set the app type to 'web' in the advanced settings
- The link I've made for the achievement comes up fine as an achievement when plugged into the debugger.

It seems like most people come unstuck when registering achievements using the wrong access_token, but I don't think that's the problem in my case. Anyone got any ideas on what else might be going wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: In my experience it's usually the 'app type' that trips people up here, because it's a little-known setting. The app isn't in sandbox mode is it? That has a similar (privacy related) effect on the ability to use the app access token sometimes

Comment: Yeah the app type is set to 'web' and sandbox mode is disabled. :(

Comment: Any chance you could attach a screenshot from the Graph Explorer when doing this?

Comment: Yep, happy to: here's a link: http://smallgreenhill.com/facebook/achievementpost.jpg (with some of the detail blanked out - hopefully none of that is pertinent) Thanks for checking it out Claudiu.

Comment: Thanks, I realise this is quite a few years later, but your link above helped me figure this out for myself. For me I didn't need anything after the achievement URL in the POST

Answer (score 0):

Just paste your generated app access token into the "Access Token Text Field" on the top part of Graph API Explorer, it does the trick for me. Hope it helps :)